# Django form validation : TypeError at /student/home conversion from dict to Decimal is not supported

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a decimalfield in my model

```
current_CGPA = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
```

I am using Modelform to validate my form

```
class StudentAcademicsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['current_CGPA']
```

I have used custom template for form rendering

```
<label class="form-label" for="current_CGPA">CGPA upto previous semester</label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="CGPA" id="current_CGPA" name="current_CGPA" {% if student.current_CGPA is not None %}value="{{student.current_CGPA}}"{% endif %} required min=0 max=10/>
            {{form.current_CGPA.errors}}
```

When i submit the request and validates form (like this)

```
user = request.user
student = Student.objects.get(user=user)
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentAcademicsForm(request.POST, instance=student)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
else:
        form = StudentAcademicsForm()
```

this error occurs:

```
TypeError at /student/home
conversion from dict to Decimal is not supported
```

On going through stacktrace i found that `get_attr()` method on my field 'current_CGPA' returns all attributes of POST in the format
`{
'current_CGPA':3,...
}`
I think its expected to return only the value '3'
But this is something done by django built-in code
So is it a bug?
Has anyone used DecimalField before?
If so then please correct me if I have done something wo

Stacktrace is shown below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/student/home

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'gep_app.apps.GepAppConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/code/gep_project/gep_app/views.py" in student_home
  49.       if form.is_valid():

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  179.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  174.             self.full_clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  378.         self._post_clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  401.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in full_clean
  1144.             self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in clean_fields
  1186.                 setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in clean
  606.         value = self.to_python(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
  1553.             return decimal.Decimal(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /student/home
Exception Value: conversion from dict to Decimal is not supported`
```

Comment: Is that the full code for StudentAcademicsForm? Have you defined any custom clean methods?

Comment: Found the solution..Yes, I had written

Comment: In the clean_field method i had returned full data, that was the issue